# Tomcat, Sessions and Browser reload

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat

We have web-application which is regularly updated and deployed on Tomcat. Also infinite session is set in tomcat configuration(there were reasons for it). When war is deployed, old websocket connection is terminated and thus users can't be notified. How can we redirect to login page on deploy or refresh web-browser page on expired sessions?

Comment: Shouldn't the websocket client be pinging the server periodically?

Comment: I think no but I can check it. Client-side connects only once.